# How to make react prevent browsers caching externally loaded html?

Tags: html, reactjs, caching

I'm using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` method to load a dynamic html from server. The issue I'm running into is, the file is getting cached and reloading the file doesn't show the changes made to it.

Is there any react method beside using `<meta>` tag to prevent caching only the loaded html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to solve this is to add a parameter to the URL you are fetching the html from. Something like:

```
const data = fetch('https://example.com/myapi/foobar?' + Date.now(), {...});
```

or with template literals if you prefer:

```
const data = fetch(`https://example.com/myapi/foobar?${Date.now()}`, {...});
```

This will concatenate the current unix timestamp to your url effectively making it always unique which will prevent browsers from caching it.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, this old technique again came to rescue!